# save an Array to cookie and then load it back to an array

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Here is the deal. This code supposed to push variable 'item' to array 'savedList'

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
var savedList = [];
 $('#button').click(function (){
    var toAdd = $('input[id=newItem]').val();
    if (toAdd =="") 
    {
        return toAdd
    } else {
    var item = '<div class="item">'+toAdd+'</div>';
    $('.shoppingScroll').prepend(item);
    $('#counter').html('You have ' + $('.item').size() + ' item(s) in you   list');
            savedList.push(item);

    }
```

});

As I understand this should .push all '.items' to my array including class specification. Question is how can I save it to cookies and then load on page start.
I attached jQuery cookie plugin to my page, but after looking documentation can't figure out how to use it.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) then just do this: `$.cookie('cookieName', cookieValue)` then on page load check if the cookie exists (`if($.cookie('cookieName')`) and if it does, loop through the results to manipulate them

Answer (score 1):

Very basic and rough code would look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var savedList = [];
    $('#button').on('click', function (){
        var toAdd = $('input[id=newItem]').val();
        if (toAdd =="") {
            return toAdd
        } else {
            var item = '<div class="item">'+toAdd+'</div>';
            $('.shoppingScroll').prepend(item);
            $('#counter').html('You have ' + $('.item').size() + ' item(s) in you   list');
            savedList.push(item);
            $.cookie('list', savedList);
        }
    });

    if($.cookie('list')) {
        $.each($.cookie('list'), function(index, val){
            console.log(val)
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: still can't get it. if i replace console.log(val) with alert("1"). nothing happens after i reload page. it does not alert any mesage. does this mean that cookie does not exists?

Comment: if you `console.log(savedList)` after the `.push(item)` what do you get? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no, it adds items to an array and I can see them into console

Comment: the problem is that I can't see it when I reload page. The cookie is not loaded

Comment: hmm, you don't have cookies turned off do you?